# Transitioning namespaces/module containers with the same name causes a conflict

Tags: typescript, namespaces

I'm trying to transition some code that was namespaced incorrectly into it's own namespace without losing current functionality (during the transition).

Original Code:

```
// (org)
module General.Admin.Dialogs {
  export class LoginDialog {
    // details
  }
}
```

After final transition:

```
// (new)
namespace Admin {
  export module Dialogs{
    export class Login {
    }
  }
}
```

However I need to keep some of the current functionality working by *aliasing* the objects in one namespace/module, however the compiler (TypeScript 2.3) isn't happy because of the naming collision (it assumes because I haven't specified the root namespace, it uses the current root namespace:

```
namespace Admin {
  export module Dialogs{
    export class Login {
    }
  }
}

module General.Admin.Dialogs {
  export var LoginDialog = Admin.Dialogs.Login;
}
```

`Admin.Dialogs.Login`  is assumed by the compiler to be in `General` (old) module/namespace and not the `Admin.Dialogs` (new) declared above.  Is there some magic I could use to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved it while writing the Quesiton, but I thought there may be other better ways or this might help someone else who is having the same difficultly so here is my answer.  Since I have to touch this file again when the transition is done, I just added another intermediate module to resolve the naming conflict (hacky, but the intermediate module will be delete too so no big deal).

```
namespace Admin {
  export module Dialogs{
    export class Login {
    }
  }
}

module AdminTransition {
  export var LoginDialog = Admin.Dialogs.Login
}

module General.Admin.Dialogs {
  export var LoginDialog = AdminTransition.LoginDialog;
}
```